# Delete Group of Records based on Group Statistic

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following two example tables

Teams

| Team ID | Team Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bears |
| 2 | Tigers |
| 3 | Lions |
| 4 | Sharks |

Players

| Player ID | Name | Team ID | Playtime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | Adam | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | Smith | 1 | 5 |
| 4 | Michelle | 2 | 5 |
| 5 | Stephanie | 2 | 10 |
| 6 | David | 2 | 10 |
| 7 | Courtney | 2 | 2 |
| 8 | Frank | 2 | 7 |
| 9 | Teresa | 2 | 1 |
| 10 | Michael | 3 | 3 |
| 11 | May | 4 | 1 |
| 12 | Daniel | 4 | 1 |
| 13 | Lisa | 4 | 4 |

I need a select statement with the following criteria

- Select all teams with less than 4 players
- Figure out the total playtime for all players on those teams and sort the resulting table based on this in descending order

Based on the example given, I would want a table that looks like this:

Teams

| Team Name | Num Players | Total Playtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bears | 3 | 14 |
| Sharks | 3 | 6 |
| Lions | 1 | 3 |

Finally, I want to cut all even rows from the previous table, so the final table would look like:

| Team Name | Num Players | Total Playtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bears | 3 | 14 |
| Lions | 1 | 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following:

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    t."Team Name",
    COUNT(p."Player ID") as "Num Players",
    SUM(p."Playtime") as "Total Playtime"
FROM
    teams t
LEFT JOIN
    players p ON t."Team ID"=p."Team ID"
GROUP BY
    t."Team Name"
HAVING
    COUNT(p."Player ID") < 4
ORDER BY 
    SUM(p."Playtime") DESC;
```

| Team Name | Num Players | Total Playtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bears | 3 | 14 |
| Sharks | 3 | 6 |
| Lions | 1 | 3 |

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT
    t1."Team Name",
    t1."Num Players",
    t1."Total Playtime"
FROM (
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(p."Playtime") DESC) as rn,
    t."Team Name",
    COUNT(p."Player ID") as "Num Players",
    SUM(p."Playtime") as "Total Playtime"
FROM
    teams t
LEFT JOIN
    players p ON t."Team ID"=p."Team ID"
GROUP BY
    t."Team Name"
HAVING
    COUNT(p."Player ID") < 4
) t1
WHERE MOD(rn,2)=1
ORDER BY rn;
```

| Team Name | Num Players | Total Playtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bears | 3 | 14 |
| Lions | 1 | 3 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gbU2pYTF6PX5ucKtfGRBzd/0)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: this worked, thanks!